# Формирование последовательности чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: python, числа, числа-фибоначчи

Программа должна формировать последовательность чисел Фибоначчи, конечное из которых не более чем целое число `N`
Вот мой код, но он работает не совсем правильно:

```
N=int(input("Enter limit"))
n=int(input("Enter number"))#количество чисел из которых будет сложена последовательность
def fib(n):
    a=0
    b=1
    for k in range(n):
        if a>=N:
            break
        a,b=b,a+b
        print(a)
    return a
print(fib(n))
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы __без явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

По сути задачи количество членов последовательности вводить не нужно, и цикл по `k` следует заменить на `while`. Что же останется? Всего-то

```
N = int(input("Enter limit: "))
a, b = 0, 1
while b < N:
    a, b = b, a+b
    print(a)
```

Если последовательность нужно не просто напечатать, то можно добавлять `a` в список.